# Split a Pandas column into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, coordinates

I have some coordinates in a csv file, formatted as [51.447084, -0.081564] that i'm reading into a pandas dataframe.

I want to split them into 2 separate columns.

I've tried

```
df[[f'Column {i}' for i in range(2)]] = df['event_location'].tolist()
```

which didn't work as my output was:

```
     event_location             Column 0           Column 1
0  [51.447084, -0.081564]  [51.447084, -0.081564]  [51.447084, -0.081564]
1    [51.447084, -0.081564]  [51.447084, -0.081564]  [51.447084, -0.081564]
```

This also didn't work

```
df[['lat', 'long']] = df['event_location'].str.split(',', expand=True)
```

Output:

```
            event_location        lat       long
0  [51.447084, -0.081564]  [51.447084, -0.081564]
1    [51.447084, -0.081564]  [51.447084, -0.081564]
```

I then thought to look at them in a list and I think this is my problem as each pair is one list item.

```
['[51.447084, -0.081564]', '[51.447084, -0.081564]']
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you provide the output of `df['event_location'].to_dict()` for reproducibility?

Comment: can you supply an example of a dataframe and its desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need:

```
df[['lat', 'lon']] = (df['event_location'].str.strip('[]')
                      .str.split(',', expand=True).astype(float)
                     )
```

Or:

```
df[['lat', 'lon']] = (df['event_location'].str.extract('(-?\d+.?\d*),(-?\d+.?\d*)')
                      .astype(float)
                     )
```

Output:

```
        event_location       lat      lon
0  [51.447084, -0.081564]  51.447084 -0.081564
1    [51.447084, -0.081564]  51.447084 -0.081564
```